# ffmpeg, how to extend video, the same clip multiple times concat

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg, video-processing

i want to extend the video clip to fixed 200 seconds even the clip is low duration in VB.Net. if video clip is 28-seconds then want to repeat concate the same clip and trim 200 seconds how to do this ?...

m trying something but i could not do how to repeat concat the same clip ...

```
  cmd = String.Format("{0} -i {1} -c copy -ss {2} -t {3} -an -y -map 0  
  {4}.m2ts",ffexe, inf, inT, ouT, ouF )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want extend or trim duration of the video by playing it in slow or fast motion. In that case, you can specify a duration for each image to display. For example if you want to display each image for one second, you can use command similar to following.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i myText.txt -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Above command is to create a video from images. Ffmpeg takes input from myText.txt file and create output.mp4 video. Inside the text file you need to give each image path with display frame duration. So video duration will be automatically set to total frame duration. Your text file will be looked likes this.

```
file '/path/to/file1'
duration 1
file '/path/to/file2'
duration 1
file '/path/to/file3'
duration 1
```

You can find more about concatenating media files in [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) link.